# How to remove noise from the signal?

Tags: noise, continuous-signals, time-series, compressive-sensing, noise-cancellation

I'm new to DSP and currently working on time-series data. The mentioned time series (of Toe) is extracted from a video tracking various body parts of an athlete. Ideally, there shouldn't be any movement in the signal and should stay around 0. I cannot explicitly make it zero, because, for other datasets, I'm not aware of what body parts are being tracked there; therefore, I need to do it in an implicit manner.

What are the noise removing techniques that can be used here? I used FFT transform, needless to mention it smoothened the signal.

[image]

Comment: Please add more details and make your question more specific. If the signal shouldn't have "any movement" and should stay around zero, why not just make it equal to zero?

Comment: How did you extract this data from the video and what are you trying to do with it? *How* did you use the FFT to smooth it out?

Comment: Although the extraction information is out of context for this video, my friend used Openpose. About FFT, I transformed the signal into the frequency domain, picked up frequency using the absolute value of the complex numbers.